# Selenium access table by xpath

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, xpath, html-table, webdriverwait

i'm fairly new to selenium and i'm building a scraper to extract info from a table.

I'm able to acces the table body by ID with no problem but when I try to access it's children they are not found.

the inspector shows the xpath for the first cell as `//*[@id="tb_list"]/tr[1]/td[1]` but

```
find_element_by_xpath(//*[@id="tb_list"]/tr[1]/td[1])
```

can't find it.

I also tried the following to no avail.

```
table = driver.find_element_by_id("tb_list")
table.find_element_by_xpath(".//tr[1]/td[1]")
```

it's able to find **tb_list** but fails to locate the children

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//tr[1]/td[1]"}
```

Everywhere I looked people suggest one of these 2 methods, what am I doing wrong? The table is dynamically populated from a database, could this be an issue?

I'm using python and the chrome web driver,
I'm hesitant to give a snippet of the html as the site is not publicly available and i dont own it.

Answer (score 0):

`[1]` indicates first descendent. So the xpath:

```
//*[@id="tb_list"]/tr[1]/td[1]
```

can be optimized as:

```
//*[@id="tb_list"]/tr/td
```

Effectively the line of code would be:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='tb_list']/tr/td")
```

Ideally, to locate the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='tb_list']/tr/td")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```